# Convert content(text) to List/Dictionary value

Tags: c#

i.e. i have in `list.txt` file:

```
{
   { "key1", "value1"},
   { "key2", "value2"},
   ....
}
```

I want to read that content as a value of dictionary variable (this is phseudo-code, i want to know how to do it actually):

```
Dictionary<string,string> xyz ...

xyz = Content_from("list.txt")
```

Comment: @mjwills How it is that same? it is not JSON format, instead comma-separated in curly brackets - default dictionary type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method like this. Make sure key and value does not contain `,` char. Otherwise use another regex for converting to JSON.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> CustomConvert(string filename)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        string text = File.ReadAllText(filename);

        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //extract every pair like:{ "key1", "value1"}
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"{[^{}]*}");

        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
        {
            //convert to JSON
            var json = match.Value.Replace(",", ":");
            var singleDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
            result.Add(singleDict.First().Key, singleDict.First().Value);
        }

        return result;
    }
```